# Default tab for case feed

Tags: servicecloud, casefeed

Is it at all possible to control the default tab inside the case feed?
[image]
The default is 'All Updates' but we'd **really** like to change this to Emails - we don't care about status updates taking top billing, they are not that important.

Answer (score 0):

This would be out of box functionality and I don't think you can set Emails as a default instead of All updates.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgVsUAJ/possibility-needed-for-fewer-updates-set-as-a-default-instead-of-all-updates).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Vinay.  Known issue then with no fix